# Getting None value for empty cell from excel python

Tags: python, excel

I have data in only 2 columns, i am getting None for empty cell

```
 import XLUtils

 path = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Book2.xlsx"
 rows=XLUtils.getRowCount(path,'Sheet2')

for r in range(2,rows+1):
   id=XLUtils.readData(path,"Sheet2",r,1)
   print(id)
   url=XLUtils.readData(path,"Sheet2",r,2)
   print(url)
```

Respone:
1
[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2
[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None

Xutil have this for read

```
def readData(file,sheetName,rownum,columnno):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
    return sheet.cell(row=rownum,column=columnno).value
```

Answer (score 1):

without having a look into your excel its difficult to say why ... but most likely, just cos you do not see data in col 3, 4, 5, it does not mean there is no data.

you could modify your readData and check for blank or None value and skip those, provided it goes well with the logic of your implementation.  That is the first option.

I will also check my excel file and do a Ctrl+End key combination.  This will take you to the end of the sheet and most likely it will not be on the cell B2 as you were expecting.

Select all the entire empty column and do the following Key combination Alt+E followed by D.

Similarly for all the empty rows.